Plotly R not displaying correct multicategory values
I am trying to build a plotly multicategory chart, but the values being displayed don't seem to match the data fed in.
Reprex data:
df <- structure(list(dsc_cat1 = c("Cat1", "Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat1", "Cat1", 
"Cat2", "Cat2", "Cat1", "Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat2", "Cat1", "Cat1", 
"Cat2", "Cat2", "Cat1", "Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat1", "Cat1", "Cat2", 
"Cat2"), dsc_cat3 = c("Var 1", "Var 2", "Var 3", "Var 1", "Var 2", 
"Var 3", "Var 4", "Var 1", "Var 2", "Var 3", "Var 4", "Var 1", 
"Var 2", "Var 5", "Var 3", "Var 1", "Var 2", "Var 3", "Var 1", 
"Var 2", "Var 3", "Var 4"), val = c(6200.63, 5358.48, 2417.35, 
8022.49, 14852.6, 2417.35, 100.93, 5389.56, 14631.52, 2417.35, 
84.39, 5387.66, 18231.84, 632.72, 1325.05, 5387.03, 14852.6, 
2417.35, 5377.88, 14087.98, 1510.02, 47.27), mth = c(1, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6)), row.names = c(NA, 
-22L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Code to produce plotly chart:
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

df %>% 
  arrange(mth, dsc_cat1) %>% 
  plot_ly(
    x = c(~mth, ~dsc_cat1)
    ,y = ~val
    ,type = "bar"
    ,color = ~dsc_cat3
  ) %>%
  layout(
    barmode = "stack"
  )

Here's the image produced by the above code:

Looking at the chart above, the values don't match what's on the data, plus the labels on the hover don't match what's on the axis either. For example, the first bar (dsc_cat1 = Cat1, dsc_cat3 = Var 1, mth = 1) value in the data should be 6201, but chart is showing close to 15k. Hover label for that bar shows 8022 instead, which seems to correspond with row 4 of the provided data (dsc_cat1 = Cat1, dsc_cat3 = Var 1, mth = 2)
A secondary issue, may or may not be related to the issue above, is that when I try to recode dsc_cat3 == Var 5 to VAR 5 I get a completely different chart:
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    dsc_cat3 = case_match(
      .x = dsc_cat3
      ,"Var 5" ~ "VAR 5"
      ,.default = dsc_cat3
    )
  )


Weirdly, this chart only shows VAR 5 and nothing else.
I have the latest plotly version:
> packageVersion("plotly")
[1] ‘4.10.4’


This looks like a limitation of plotly, which has been addressed before. A workaround is to use subplot, passing a mutated dataset (not filtered on mth as in the previous answer, but mutating the val to be 0 so that all categories of dsc_cat3 are shown in the legend (not all appear in every month).
subplot(
  lapply(unique(df$mth), function(m) {
    
    data <- df %>%  
      mutate(df, val=ifelse(mth==m, val, 0)) %>%
      arrange(dsc_cat1) 
    
    x_title <- paste("Month", m)  
    show_legend = ifelse(m == 1, TRUE, FALSE)
    
    plot_ly(data = data, 
            x = ~dsc_cat1,
            y = ~val,
            type = "bar",
            legendgroup=~dsc_cat3,
            color = ~dsc_cat3,
            showlegend=show_legend
    ) %>% 
      layout(xaxis = list(title = x_title))
  }), titleX = TRUE, shareY = TRUE) %>% 
  layout(barmode = 'stack', showlegend = TRUE)




Thanks @Edward, subplot fixes both issues for me
